# Get list item by title

Tags: list, sharepoint-2010

Can anyone help me with this problem.
The thing is, I have list and in which there are items. Normally we access the list items by ID and not by title.

```
/Lists/Issue%20Log/DispForm.aspx?ID=118&ContentTypeId=0x010001B2A64F3F5AF64BB47CC5044286787E
```

we got new requirement to access the list item by TITLE

```
/Lists/Issue%20Log/DispForm.aspx?Title=Help me to call list item by title.
```

By access Item with title is not working.
Can anyone pls let me know what I have to do to get the list item by Title.

Comment: can any one help me here with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would bet that it is not possible out of the box.

1. You could add a filter WebPart and help them locate their Item more easily. Or
2. You could create a WebPart that reads the URL Query does a lookup (provided titles are unique) and redirects the page to display the desired Item.

good luck!

Comment: is there any documentation that this cannot be done out of box? i will try 2 option as it display items by title. please provide any link of documentation that says it is not possible out of box. Thank you :)

Will Data View Webpart will work ???

Answer (score 0):

it is possible try it like this:

```
http://yourSharePoint.com/Lists/ListName/DispForm.aspx?Title=YourItemTitle
```

Hope it helps